# Strongly differentiable function has inverse satisfying Lipschitz condition

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation, differential, lipschitz-functions

> **Problem Statement:** Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be open, and $K\subset U$, compact. If $f\in C^{1}(U;\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and $df\in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^{m},\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is injective for each $\mathbf{x}\in K$, then $\exists c,r>0$ so that $\lVert f(\mathbf{x})-f(\mathbf{y})\rVert \geq c\lVert \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\rVert$ whenever $\mathbf{x}\in K$, $\mathbf{y}\in U$, and  $\lVert \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\rVert <r$. ($\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^{m},\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is the set of bounded linear maps $T:\mathbb{R}^{m}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$)

I am working on this problem, and I have a theorem that I think will be helpful, but I am unsure how to apply it.

First, the $f$ given in the problem statement is strongly differentiable.

Also, the theorem states that if $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is strongly differentiable at $\mathbf{a}\in U\subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$, $U$ open, and $df(\mathbf{a})\in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^{m},\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is injective, then $\exists c,r>0$, such that $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in B_{r}(\mathbf{a})$ implies $\lVert f(\mathbf{x})-f(\mathbf{y})\rVert \geq c\lVert \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\rVert$.

The difference between this case and the problem statement is that we must show that for *any* $\mathbf{x}\in K\subset U$, $\mathbf{y}\in U$, the same inequality holds, while in the theorem, these two points $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ must be inside a ball of finite radius centered at $\mathbf{a}$.

We know that $df(\mathbf{x})$ is injective for $\mathbf{x}\in K$, but it is not true for any $\mathbf{y}\in U$. I was thinking to consider $B_{r}(\mathbf{x})$, but we must show that the distance between any point in $U$ and another in $K$ is finite, which I am not sure how to do, since $U$ is not  necessarily bounded.

I am also confused what it means for $df(\mathbf{a})$ to be injective. Would that not be an explicit point in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, since it is the differential of $f$ evaluated at $\mathbf{a}$? Or is the theorem essentially saying the conclusion holds if it is injective at any point in which the function is strongly differentiable?

Any suggestions on how to approach this problem are appreciated!

Comment: I think you need $x$ and $y$ to be uniformly $\epsilon$-close with $\epsilon$ small enough (like in the thorem you state). Otherwise you may map a circle in the plane to a figure 8 to contradict the statement.

Comment: what is this "strongly differentiable"?

Comment: By definition, $f:U\rightarrow R^{n}$ is *strongly differentiable* at $a\in U$ if $\exists T\in \mathcal{L}(R^{m},R^{n})$ and a function $r_{a}(x,y)$, $x,y\in U$ so that for any $x,y\in U$: $$f(x)-f(y)=T[x-y]+r_{a}(x,y)$$
where $\lim_{x\rightarrow a,y\rightarrow a} \frac{r_{a}(x,y)}{\lVert x-y\rVert }=0$.

Comment: Also known as "differentiable" in the trade.

Comment: @zhw. :  No, strong differentiability is stronger than differentiability; in the definition in the comment before yours, neither $x$ nor $y$ is required to be $a$.  For example, $x \mapsto x^2 \sin(1/x^2)$ (extended by continuity) is differentiable everywhere but not strongly differentiable at $0$.

Comment: @TobyBartels You're right, I didn't read the definition carefully.

Answer (score 1):

To apply the known theorem, you can use a general trick for compact sets: if you have a result that holds at every point in this set, and if one of the things that this result gives you at each point is a neighbourhood of that point, then you've got an open cover of the compact set, so pass to a finite subcover so that you can focus attention on finitely many points; that might be enough.

So in this case, take the collection of all triples $(\mathbf{a},c,r) \in K \times (0,\infty) \times (0,\infty)$ such that for $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in U$, $\lVert{f(\mathbf{x})-f(\mathbf{y})}\rVert \geq c\,\lVert{\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}}\rVert$ whenever $\lVert{\mathbf{a}-\mathbf{x}}\rVert < r$ and $\lVert{\mathbf{a}-\mathbf{y}}\rVert < r$; each such triple defines an open set $B_{r/2}(\mathbf{a})$.  Your theorem guarantees that each $\mathbf{a} \in K$ (indeed each $\mathbf{a} \in U$) shows up in at least one such triple; since $\mathbf{a} \in B_{r/2}(\mathbf{a})$, this means that these open sets form an open cover of $K$.  So there is a finite subcover, indexed by a finite collection of triples $(\mathbf{a}_i,c_i,r_i)$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n$.  Let $c$ be $\min_i c_i$, and let $r$ be $\min_i (r_i/2)$ (which is why we need a *finite* subcover).  Then if $\lVert{\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}}\rVert < r$ for some $\mathbf{x} \in K$ and $\mathbf{y} \in U$, we have $\mathbf{x} \in B_{r_i/2}(\mathbf{a}_i)$ for some $\mathbf{a}_i$ (which is why we need a finite *subcover*), so $\lVert{\mathbf{a}_i-\mathbf{x}}\rVert < r_i/2 < r_i$ and $$\lVert{\mathbf{a}_i-\mathbf{y}}\rVert \leq \lVert{\mathbf{a}_i-\mathbf{x}}\rVert + \lVert{\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}}\rVert < r_i/2 + r \leq r_i/2 + r_i/2 = r_i$$  (which is why I had divide $r$ by $2$ all the time), so $\lVert{f(\mathbf{x})-f(\mathbf{y})}\rVert \geq c_i\,\lVert{\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}}\rVert \geq c\,\lVert{\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}}\rVert$, QED.

Answer (score 0):

If the theorem fails, then for each choice of $c,r>0,$ there are $x\in K,y\in U$ with $|y-x|<r$ and $|f(y)-f(x)|<c|y-x|.$ In particular, for $c=r=1/k,k=1,2,\dots,$ there exist $x_k\in K,y_k\in U$ with $|y_k-x_k|<1/k$ and $|f(y_k)-f(x_k)|<(1/k)|y_k-x_k|.$

Now $K$ is compact, so there exists a subsequence $x_{k_j}$ converging to some $x_0\in K.$ Because $|y_{k_j}-x_{k_j}|<1/k_j,$ we also have $y_{k_j}\to x_0.$ By the theorem we are given, there exist $c,r>0$ that "work" in $B(x_0,r).$ But for large $j$ we will have $1/k_j$ smaller than both $c$ and $r/2.$ For such $j$ we then have $x_{k_j},y_{k_j}\in B(x_0,r),$ while $|f(y_{k_j})-f(x_{k_j})|<(1/k_j)|y_{k_j}-x_{k_j}|<c|y_{k_j}-x_{k_j}|.$ That's a contradiction, proving the desired result.

**Note**: The above replaces an earlier answer to an earlier question.

Comment: But isn't the requirement that $f'$ is injective, and linear?

Comment: If in one variable $f'(a)\ne 0$ then we have $df(a)$ injective. Not sure why you're asking about "linear".

Comment: Because the problem statement says that the differential is a bounded linear map. But also, there was one important part of the conclusion left out (which I just edited), the conclusion is only truewhen $x$ and $y$ have finite distance.

Comment: All differentials are bounded linear maps in finite dimensions. So we're left with the hypotheses you left out, although I missed your apology for doing so. Btw, $x$ and $y$ always have finite distance.

Comment: I am sorry. And yes I realize that it is a linear map now. I am confusing the notion of a derivative with a differential map. I understand how to solve the problem now.

Comment: OK, no problem.

Comment: This is *not* a counterexample to the conjecture stated in the question.  That $f(\pi/3) = f(2\pi/3)$ only shows that we need $r \leq \lvert{2\pi/3 - \pi/3}\rvert$, so that $2\pi/3$ is not an allowed value for $\mathbf{y}$.  Indeed, the result is true in this case; one can use any $r < \pi/3$ and $c < 1$, so long as $r c < \sin(\pi/3 + r) - \sin(\pi/3)$.

Comment: @TobyBartels It is a counterexample to the question as originally stated.

Comment: Ah, I see, I should have examined the timestamps and the edit history.

Comment: A few hours ago, somebody asked me to edit an answer that I'd given so that they could remove a downvote, and now I find myself in the same embarrassing position!  Perhaps you could edit your answer to note that it refers to the question before it was edited?

Comment: @TobyBartels Don't worry about it, I'll probably delete this answer anyway.

Comment: @TobyBartels I decided to give an answer to the question as it now stands.

Comment: Nice!  (You got downvoted more, but I don't know why; it's not from me.)